# What does 'common twitch' stand for in this statement?

Tags: idioms

I would like to get to know what the meaning of common twitch is here?

Because giving into old temptation
is like that common twitch.

Answer (score 1):

A **twitch** is a muscle spasm. **Common** means familiar.

**That common twitch** is *Delirium Tremens* ("the shakes"), a symptom of alcohol withdrawal. It is a serious medical condition caused by the nervous system going into shock when deprived of the chemical fix. DTs can kill so it was sometimes preferable to stay addicted than to quit.

DTs marked the end and beginning of a drinking cycle so it becomes a metaphor for anxiety, fatalism, helplessness, and the addiction itself.